# Asp.net attribute routing working locally but fails when deployed on live server

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, routes, attributes, asp.net-mvc-routing

I am using aspnet mvc attribute routing, everything works well locally but fails once it is deployed on the server. My route config looks like this

```
public class RouteConfig
{
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes();

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Error",
            url:"error/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" }
        );

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );           
    }
}
```

I have a url action in my index view that redirects to the correct route / action in the controller

```
<a href="@Url.HttpRouteUrl("zoro", new { adID = myAdID, Desc = urlDesc })" style="width:100%; height:250px; display:block; cursor:pointer;">
```

Then in my controller I have this

```
[Route("ViewSingleAdID", Name = "zoro")]
public ActionResult ViewSingleAdID(int adID, string Desc)
    {
        // set some variables
        return RedirectToAction("ViewSingleAd", new { Desc = Desc });
    }

[Route("ViewAd/{Desc}")]
public ActionResult ViewSingleAd(string Desc)
{
    // code which returns view
    return View();
}
```

This works perfectly locally but why does it fail on the deployed version on the server?